# Loop variable inside of a loop

Tags: python, variables, attributes, declaration

I got the following code:

```
    if os.path.exists("data/ao-1.dat"):
        logininfo = open("data/ao-1.dat", "r").read().split()
        if len(loginInfo[0]) > 0:
            self.AccountsList.connect_1.SetText(logininfo[0])
        else:
            self.AccountsList.connect_1.SetText("Save")
    else:
        self.AccountsList.connect_1.SetText("Save")

##dupe

        if os.path.exists("data/ao-2.dat"):
            logininfo = open("data/ao-2.dat", "r").read().split()
            if len(loginInfo[0]) > 0:
                self.AccountsList.connect_2.SetText(logininfo[0])
            else:
                self.AccountsList.connect_2.SetText("Save")
        else:
            self.AccountsList.connect_2.SetText("Save")
```

Is there any possibility so I can use loop variable to for attribute in Python? I want to prevent from duplicating the above code just for one number.

The following wont work:

```
for i in xrange(1, 3):
     if os.path.exists("data/ao-" + str(i) + ".dat"):
          logininfo = open("data/ao-" + str(i) + ".dat", "r").read().split()
          if len(loginInfo[0]) > 0:
                self.AccountsList.connect_(i).SetText(logininfo[0]) #problem
          else:
                self.AccountsList.connect_(i).SetText("Save") #problem
     else:
          self.AccountsList.connect_(i).SetText("Save") #problem
```

because python dont follow to declare variables as attribute names so it there any way to make a loop out there or I will have to duplicate the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr()` function to get an attribute by name.

Also, use string formatting instead of string concatenation and `with` for manipulating file. Also you can simplify the code a little bit by making if/else in one line:

```
for i in xrange(1, 3):
    if os.path.exists("data/ao-%d.dat" % i):
        with open("data/ao-%d.dat" % i) as f:
            logininfo = f.read().split()

        text = logininfo[0] if logininfo[0] else "Save"
        getattr(self.AccountsList, 'connect_%d' % i).SetText(text)
    else:
        getattr(self.AccountsList, 'connect_%d' % i).SetText("Save")
```

Plus, there was an error in naming: `loginInfo` vs `logininfo`.

Comment: I get an error message with `Invalid Syntax` at this line: `with open("data/ao-%d.dat" % i, "r") as f:`.

Comment: Are you sure that `width open[...]` is going to work properly with Python 2.1 ?

Comment: @Lucas python 2.1, are you serious? Not sure, revert to a one-liner `read()` in this case.

Comment: python 2.2* , sorry but yeah I don't have a possibility to update it atm.

Answer (score 3):

```
getattr(self.AccountsList, 'connect_%d' % i).SetText(logininfo[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should use `getattr()`. Another general comment is that this level of nesting in your code is usually an indication that you should redesign your code to be more modular - having multiple levels of nesting as you do in your code makes it very difficult to read and/or debug.